# Reasonably secure way to allow table name access on client side

Tags: ajax

We have a need coming up in an application where the following is true:

- A web page uses AJAX to request data from a server.
- The specification of the data (e. g. table name) requested from the server will not be known until run-time.
- The configuration of the data view is itself data-driven, and configurable by an administrator.
- Data updates and inserts must be supported, not just views.

Prototyping this was very easy - we could pass in the appropriate information (table name, changeset, whatever) to a generic data service that just did what it was told (using JSON as the data storage mechanism).  The data service could do basic validation on the parameters to ensure the current user can perform the requested operation (read the data, insert a row, read the row).

The issue we have now that we are looking to doing this is a secure production manner, and the idea of passing table names and column names is frightening.  Everything we think of to deal with this devolves into trusting the client in some significant way, or seems to involve substantial bookkeeping on the server.  For example:

1. User requests a viewing page.
2. The server notes the table name and saves it server side with a request ID
3. The server notes the column names and saves them, replacing them with "col1, col2", etc., and stores the mapping with the request ID data.
4. The client page sends the request ID to the service, which looks up the server storage by ID
5. The service returns col1, col2, etc.

This would work, we think, but feels very messy.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of problem and can offer a solution?

Comment: This begs the question: why?  Is this a database administration tool?

Comment: The end customer needs to be able to add references to their own data sources and schemas with no intervention from us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to expose back-end information to end customers, I'd probably hide the actual physical representation using meta-data that would remap table names and columns to more user-friendly text, that would also enable me to provide views on the tables that are a bit more advanced than plain table / column names... As properly modeling associations between tables and so on...

Comment: Just to follow up, this is eventually what it looks like we are going to do - we are going to use an ORM and expose the ORM layer indirectly.  The ORM layer will act as that mapping layer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to give them access to raw tables?
Perhaps you can go meta, and make a meta-table that stores the tabular data in a secure manner (ie, only the system knows the table/schema, but the user's concept of schema/table are just abstractions that all map back to the same schema/table)...

Again, more information is needed as to what can be abstracted.  Allowing [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) operations by the end-users is asking for trouble, as you rightfully assessed, and I would just abstract that so that "DDL" becomes DML.

However, mapping actual SQL that is written against this data would be much more difficult to abstract, if that is a requirement.

Comment: To answer your questions, DDL would not be needed.  Raw tables is necessary primarily because the whole point of the system is that if we knew the data to be accessed ahead of time, we could provide a layer in the middle e. g. sprocs that allowed the data access and changes.  We don't need actual SQL.  Instead the thought is more "user has table ABC in database X that we didn't know about, and they want to show a grid on a new page that has that table".